# SQL with clause in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, with-statement

Is it possible to define a with clause in a stored procedure and use it in if else statements because I always get an error?

```
BEGIN
    WITH Test (F, A) AS
    (
        SELECT FM.ID, FM.Name 
        FROM [Test.Abc] FM
        INNER JOIN [Organization] O on O.ABCID = FM.ID
    )

    IF(@var = 'case1')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM Test F
        WHERE NOT F.ID = 'someID'
    END
```

I always get an "Incorrect syntax" error before the if statement

If I move the with clause into the if statement it works fine. But I need the with statement outside to reuse it in different if else statements.

Comment: You'd better describe whole scenario. Right now it looks weird: your sp may return result set and may not to. How to work with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another version of the same answers you're getting:

Your `with` `common table expresson` has to be in the same statement as the query that calls it, and it has to be referenced by a query (or other `cte`) or it is a syntax error.

Reference the documentation Guidelines for **Creating and Using [Common Table Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)**.

```
BEGIN -- doing stuff
-- .... doing stuff over here
IF(@var = 'case1')
    BEGIN
        with Test (F, A) as ( -- You define columns ID as F and Name as A
        select FM.ID, FM.Name from [Test.Abc] FM
        inner join [Organization] O on O.ABCID = FM.ID
          )     
        select * from Test 
        where not F = 'someID' -- You must use the new columna name (F)
    END
-- .... and doing some other stuff over here too
END -- done with this stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a temporary table or table variable.  The scoping rules of SQL Server ensure that such a table is dropped at the end of the procedure:

```
BEGIN
    select FM.ID, FM.Name
    into #test
    from [Test.Abc] FM inner join
         [Organization] O
         on O.ABCID = FM.ID;

    IF(@var = 'case1')
        BEGIN
            select *
            from #Test F
            where not F.ID = 'someID'
        END;
```

This has the advantage that you can add indexes to the table, and these might improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

WITH is not a standalone, it always a part of a whole statement and only one statement.
It is not recognizable outside the scope ofits statement.

```
BEGIN

    with my_cte (n) as (select 1+1)
    select * from my_cte

    -- The following statement yields the error "Invalid object name 'my_cte'."    
    -- select * from my_cte

END
```